# How to join thread in drop function?

Tags: rust

I want to stop a thread after a structure "goes away":

```
use std::thread;

struct Foo {
    handle: thread::JoinHandle<()>,
}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("we drop data");
        self.handle.join();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let handle = thread::spawn(|| println!("hi from thread"));
    let _ = Foo { handle: handle };
}
```

but it doesn't compile:

```
error[E0509]: cannot move out of type `Foo`, which implements the `Drop` trait
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         self.handle.join();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of here
```

This is because `join` takes `self`, not `&mut self`. How can I join this thread in the `drop` method?

Comment: One way would be to store `Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>` and `.take()` it in the `Drop` impl.

Comment: @Dogbert I thought about mem::replace, but looks like no way to create empty JoinHandle for replacement.